# Schedulling tasks on different plateforms

Tags: windows, linux, scheduling, windows-server, job-scheduler

We have a mix of Linux, OSX and Windows servers that use crontab, Windows Task Scheduler, etc to run a bunch of bash/windows scripts, rsync commands, etc.

I would like to replace these OS specific schedulers with a centrally controlled system to get a getter overview, preferably something with a web console.

I found this list of software on wikipedia which is, to put it mildly, overwhelming. I'm hoping someone could help me narrow it down a little, or suggest something else.

The requirements are as follows:

- Web based console for configuration, execution, etc
- Time based triggers similar to crontab or windows scheduler. Ideally also possible to select days in a calendar as we are a seasonal business which is open weekends only during spring/autumn, all week during summer in addition to Easter. Right now we have to manually adjust the windows task scheduler as the season progress.
- Can start scripts on remote machines for all major platforms (Linux, OSX, Windows).
- Possible to view logs from scripts on remote machines (some outputs to stdout, others to a specific logfile).
- Retain logfiles for all executions.
- Alerting mechanism if a job fails, preferably with some regex testing on the stdout as not all executable use exit codes as expected.
- We only have 15-20 jobs all up, so nothing too fancy is necessary.